# Raspberry Pi 3b not connecting to WIFI

Tags: wifi, connection

Been through all the forums and having no luck. I have tried the following:
*Channel - using 6 and all 13 showing available
*WiFI source - tried changing router to non UK, but not possible, changed Pi to Us
*Run set via pixel and command. Command showing wifi networks available with correct passwords
*SSH set to enabled

I have not managed to get on via wifi once. Ethernet working fine. Please help a brother out!

Comment: Unless you are more specific about what you tried and what you changed all you can hope (at best) is more answers like those you have found.

Answer (score 1):

-- Answer completely changed:

First, I look at these two commands to get a feel for what it is doing:

```
ifconfig
iwconfig
```

The first one will tell you if your wlan interface(s) have an address
The second tells you if you are connected to a router or not.

If it insists on connecting to another router then you want to edit this file:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and delete any network sections other than the one you want.

If the IP address is not correct, you will want to go to

```
sudo leafpad /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

and make sure there is only a single entry for the interface you are trying to use, with the correct IP and gateway addresses.

Then reboot.

By then, iwconfig should show that you are connected to your router, and ifconfig should show you have a proper IP address.

Comment: OK, I put in the time to figure this out and you are indeed right.  wicd-curses kept simply adding to the dhcpcd.conf file and there were multiple sections that were conflicting.  I cleared out all but the one I needed and it works.  I even totally took out the wlan0 section and now the swap isn't happening, either..  Thanks for the tip.